# How to Perform Global Search in Angular 8/9?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Please find my existing script,

Directory Structure:

```
App/
->Classes
->Components
->Services Index.html
```

Script Sample:

Index.html

```
<html lang="en">
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>

          <app-root></app-root>

        </body>
        </html>
```

App/app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

// Datepicker module
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

import { OwlModule } from 'ngx-owl-carousel';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/carousel';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    OwlModule,
    CarouselModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BsDatepickerModule
  ],
  providers: [CookieService, Title, { provide: 'BASE_API_URL', useValue: environment.baseUrl}],

      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {
      constructor() {}
    }
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Header Component HTML:

```
<header class="site-header">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="align-items-center row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
              <div class="logo">
                <a [routerLink]="['/']">
                  <img src="assets/images/deluxify-logo.png" alt="Deluxify">
                </a>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9">
              <div class="headertopright">
              <nav class="main-navigation">
                  <ul class="menu">
                      <li><a [routerLink]="['categories']">Discover</a></li>
                      <li><a [routerLink]="['how-it-works']">How It Works</a></li>
                      <li><a [routerLink]="['faq']">FAQ</a></li>
                      <li><a [routerLink]="['contact']">Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </nav>
              <div class="searchbox">
                  <div class="txtdiv">
                  <input type="text" 
                    placeholder="Search" 
                    name="search" class="searchfield" 
                    autocomplete="off"
                  >
                </div>

                <div class="selectDiv">
                  <select id="head_category">
                    <option value="bags">Bags</option>
                    <option value="jewellery">Jewellery</option>
                    <option value="sunglasses">Sunglasses</option>
                    <option value="watches">Watches</option>

                  </select>
                </div>

              </div>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="togglemenu menu-trigger">
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
              </a>
              <a [routerLink]="['/','category', 'bags']" class="togglesearch searchicon"></a>


          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Header Component TS file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    declare var jQuery:any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-header',
      templateUrl: './header.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
    })
    export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() {}

      ngOnInit() {



      }

    }
```

Search Component ts

```
    import { Component, EventEmitter, Output, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Params, Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { Options, ChangeContext, PointerType, LabelType } from 'ng5-slider';
    import { ProductService } from './../../services/product.service';
    import { CategoryService } from './../../services/category.service';
    import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';

    declare var jQuery: any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-product',
      templateUrl: './product.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
    })
    export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

      filterOptions:any = {};
      products: any;
      notEmptyPost = true;
      notscrolly = true;
      isCatLoaded = false;
      dataLength: any;
      catname: any;
      error: {};
      config: any;
      brandArr: any[] = [];
      idealforArr: any[] = [];
      shapeArr: any[] = [];
      framecolorArr: any[] = [];
      typeArr: any[] = [];
      colorArr: any[] = [];
      meterialArr: any[] = [];
      sizeArr: any[] = [];
      styleArr: any[] = [];
      stoneArr: any[] = [];
      weightArr: any[] = [];
      occasionArr: any[] = [];
      framesizeArr: any[] = [];
      lenscolorArr: any[] = [];
      frame_typeArr: any[] = [];
      frame_materialArr: any[] = [];
      strap_materialArr: any[] = [];
      strap_colorArr: any[] = [];
      dial_colorArr: any[] = [];
      dial_ShapeArr: any[] = [];


      constructor(
        private ProductService: ProductService, 
        private CategoryService: CategoryService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute, 
        private router: Router,
        private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {

        this.config = {
          currentPage: 1,
          itemsPerPage: 16,
          totalItems: 0,
          filterPerms: {}
        };
        this.config.filterPerms.slug = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('slug')? this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('slug') : 'bags';
      }


      priceSliderMinValue: number = 100;
      priceSliderMaxValue: number = 9999;
      options: Options = {
        floor: this.priceSliderMinValue,
        ceil: this.priceSliderMaxValue,
        step: 10,
        // showTicks: true,
        translate: (value: number, label: LabelType): string => {
          switch (label) {
            case LabelType.Low:
              return '$' + value;
            case LabelType.High:
              return '$' + value;
            default:
              return '$' + value;
          }
        }
      };

      onPriceChangeEnd(changeContext: ChangeContext): void {
        this.config.filterPerms.min_price = changeContext.value;
        this.config.filterPerms.max_price = changeContext.highValue;
        this.resetLoadMore();
        this.getProducts();
      }

      value: number = 1;
      highValue: number = 10;
      optionsdistance: Options = {
        floor: 1,
        ceil: 10,
        step: 1,
        showTicks: true,
        translate: (value: number, label: LabelType): string => {
          switch (label) {
            case LabelType.Low:
              return value + 'KM';
            case LabelType.High:
              return value + 'KM';
            default:
              return value + 'KM';
          }
        }
      };


      brandChecked(event){
        let sCriteriaStr = event.target.name;
        let sCriteria = sCriteriaStr.replace("chk_", "");

        if (sCriteria === 'brand') {
          this.config.filterPerms.brand = this.findSearchableString(event, this.brandArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'idealfor') {
          this.config.filterPerms.idealfor = this.findSearchableString(event, this.idealforArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'shape') {
          this.config.filterPerms.shape = this.findSearchableString(event, this.shapeArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'framecolor') {
          this.config.filterPerms.framecolor = this.findSearchableString(event, this.framecolorArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'type') {
          this.config.filterPerms.type = this.findSearchableString(event, this.typeArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'color') {
          this.config.filterPerms.color = this.findSearchableString(event, this.colorArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'meterial') {
          this.config.filterPerms.meterial = this.findSearchableString(event, this.meterialArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'size') {
          this.config.filterPerms.size = this.findSearchableString(event, this.sizeArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'style') {
          this.config.filterPerms.style = this.findSearchableString(event, this.styleArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'stone') {
          this.config.filterPerms.stone = this.findSearchableString(event, this.stoneArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'weight') {
          this.config.filterPerms.weight = this.findSearchableString(event, this.weightArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'occasion') {
          this.config.filterPerms.occasion = this.findSearchableString(event, this.occasionArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'framesize') {
          this.config.filterPerms.framesize = this.findSearchableString(event, this.framesizeArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'lenscolor') {
          this.config.filterPerms.lenscolor = this.findSearchableString(event, this.lenscolorArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'frame_type') {
          this.config.filterPerms.frame_type = this.findSearchableString(event, this.frame_typeArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'frame_material') {
          this.config.filterPerms.frame_material = this.findSearchableString(event, this.frame_materialArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'strap_material') {
          this.config.filterPerms.strap_material = this.findSearchableString(event, this.strap_materialArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'strap_color') {
          this.config.filterPerms.strap_color = this.findSearchableString(event, this.strap_colorArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'dial_color') {
          this.config.filterPerms.dial_color = this.findSearchableString(event, this.dial_colorArr, sCriteria);
        }
        if (sCriteria === 'dial_Shape') {
          this.config.filterPerms.dial_Shape = this.findSearchableString(event, this.dial_ShapeArr, sCriteria);
        }
        this.resetLoadMore();
        this.getProducts();
      }

      findSearchableString(event, checkedArr, filterOptionKey){
        let tVal =  event.target.value;
        if(event.target.checked) {
          checkedArr.push(tVal);
        }
        else {
          for(var i=0 ; i < this.filterOptions[filterOptionKey].length; i++) {
            if(checkedArr[i] === tVal) {
              checkedArr.splice(i,1);
            }
          }
        }
        return checkedArr.join('~');
      }


      onDateChange(event) {
        if (event) {
          var dtEvent = new Date(event);
          let date = JSON.stringify(dtEvent)
          date = date.slice(1,11);
          if (date) {
            this.config.filterPerms.availability_date = date;
            this.resetLoadMore();
            this.getProducts();
          }
        }
      }

      // pageChanged(event) {
      //   this.config.currentPage = event;
      // }

      getFilterOptions() {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
            this.route.params.pipe(
              switchMap((params: Params) => this.CategoryService.getCategoryBySlug(this.config.filterPerms.slug)
              )
            ).subscribe((res: any) => {
              this.config.filterPerms.category = res.records;
              this.isCatLoaded=true;
              if (this.config.filterPerms.category[0].id) {
                this.route.params.pipe(
                  switchMap((params: Params) => this.ProductService.getFilterOptions(this.config)
                  )
                ).subscribe((res: any) => {
                  this.filterOptions = res;

                  this.priceSliderMinValue = this.filterOptions.min;
                  this.priceSliderMaxValue = this.filterOptions.max;

                  resolve();
                });
              }
            });  
          });
      }

      getProducts() {
        this.spinner.show();
        this.route.params.pipe(
            switchMap((params: Params) => this.ProductService.getFilterProducts(this.config)
          )
        ).subscribe((res: any) => {
          if (!res.success) {
            console.log("Error found in fetching data!");
          } else {
            this.spinner.hide();
            this.products = res.records;
          }
        });
      }

      sortBy(sort_by) {
        this.config.filterPerms.sort_by = sort_by.target.value;
        if (sort_by) {
          this.resetLoadMore();
          this.getProducts();
        }
      }

      resetLoadMore() {
        this.config.filterPerms.lastPostId = '';
        this.config.filterPerms.curNumRec = '';
      }

      onScroll() {
        if (this.notscrolly && this.notEmptyPost) {
          this.spinner.show();
          this.notscrolly = false;
          this.loadNextPost(); 
         }
      }
      // load th next 6 posts
      loadNextPost() {   
        if (this.isCatLoaded && this.products) {
          const lastPost = this.products[0];
          //this.config.filterPerms.lastPostId = lastPost.id;
          this.config.filterPerms.curNumRec = this.products.length;
          this.route.params.pipe(
            switchMap((params: Params) => this.ProductService.getFilterProducts(this.config)
            )).subscribe((res: any) => {
              this.spinner.hide();
              if (res.records.length === 0 ) {
                  this.notEmptyPost =  false;
              }
              this.products = this.products.concat(res.records);
              this.notscrolly = true;
          });
        }
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.getFilterOptions().then(res => this.getProducts());
      }
   }
```

I am facing issue in search from header all filter script performs perfectly which are write in search component but search by keyword defined in header component then how to perform search from header.

Both component are parent there is no relation between child and parent concept you can view the component relation in app.component.html file.

Search page load on demand and header footer page load while start the project.

So please help anyone how to do it with better way.

Comment: Maybe make a service with an observable you can listen to?

Comment: No actually I  am new in Angular so would you brief me with more detail if it possible.

Comment: I would suggest that you continue learning the basics. Especially service injection and observables. Posting the whole project without any context does not help. If you want others help then you should also take some efforts to ask properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have done so far is completely fine. I have created a working example of the code I have below: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khwjt3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

---

First, need to add a new service. This service will relay all search input events out to anything in your app that listens to it.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalSearchService {
    public searchTerm: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
}
```

**HeaderComponent.html** Add a new input event to your search box

```
<input (input)="onInput($event)" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search" class="searchfield" autocomplete="off" >
```

**HeaderComponent.ts** Add an event listener for it

```
public onInput(event: any){
     // this pushes the input value into the service's Observable.
     this.globalSearchService.searchTerm.next(event.target.value);
}
```

**Product Component.ts** Now we just have to subscribe to our new Observable.

```
ngOnInit(){
    // this listens to the input value from the service and does something on change.
     this.globalSearchService.searchTerm.subscribe((newValue: string) => {
    // this is where you would apply your existing filtering.
       this.searchTerm = newValue;
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zze, solved my problem, you write exactly same which i need :)